# ng-show,ng hide is working. but ng if is not working

Tags: angularjs

**ng-show,ng hide** is working.  but **ng if is not working**

```
 <svg  ng-show="abc.chartLoaded" ></svg>
 <div class="loader" ng-hide="abc.chartLoaded"></div>
```

this code is working,, but i need it shoud be in ng-if.

```
  <svg  ng-if="abc.chartLoaded == 'true'" ></svg>
     <div class="loader" ng-if="abc.chartLoaded == 'false'></div>
```

this code is not working!!!
and my js code is:

```
  scope.initExplorer = function() {
    scope.widget.chartLoaded='true';}
```

any help please!!!

Comment: why not just use `ng-if="abc.chartLoaded"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes. Or better, remove the == true and == false and use booleans for more stable conditions:

```
<svg  ng-if="abc.chartLoaded" ></svg>
<div class="loader" ng-if="!abc.chartLoaded"></div>
```

JS

```
scope.initExplorer = function() {
scope.widget.chartLoaded=true;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting `scope.widget.chartLoaded` in your `initExplorer`; however, you're template is referencing `abc.chartLoaded`.  It should be `widget.chartLoaded`.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean values in Javascript are `false` and `true` without the quotes. `'true'` is considered a string and it is not the same thing.

Note that there are also [truthy and falsy](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md#truthy--falsy) values: `if(0){}` is the same thing as `if(false){}`.

**Back to your example:**

Since `'true'` is truthy, `ng-show="abc.chartLoaded"` and `ng-if="abc.chartLoaded"` would resolve to true, which will show your element.

I would recommend using `false` and `true` to avoid confusion.

When you attach an attribute to `scope` object, it becomes available in your html template with the same name.

Try this in your controller:

```
scope.widget = {}; //you need to initialize widget if not done elsewhere

scope.initExplorer = function() {
    scope.widget.chartLoaded = true;
}
```

And in your html:

```
<svg  ng-if="widget.chartLoaded" ></svg>
```